# Passing Flowfile to FetchHdfs processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi Flow which will fetch Active NameNode, And put the NN ip into Flow File Attribute. Now i want to use the NN attribute in next application which is a fetchHDFS processor.

But its seems like flowFile in queue is not Flowing through FetchHDFS processor.

[image]

This is the attribute of flowFile, and i'am interested in host_ip, Host_name

[image]

**Update**

I want to dynamically change the hdfs path/ActiveNN etc for getting data, so all that information will be present in the flowfile attribute.

Below image is my requirement, Path and host_ip will be present in the flowfile attribute, if fetchHDFS not the correct way, the how can i achieve this.

[image]

Comment: What does it mean `flowFile in queue is not Flowing through FetchHDFS processor`

Comment: Hi @daggett , it means, you can see from above image(1st one) there is one flowFile in Queue. But It is not picking by fetchHDFS processor. In that flowFile im having all the info like HDFS path, Active NameNOde etc

Comment: @daggett If you see the second image , that is the attribute of queued flowFile, So i need to access that host_ip and host_name in fetchHDFS processor

Comment: seems fetchhdfs does not support dynamic source server.

Comment: @daggett, Is there any alternative that i can use, to achieve this.  Lets say if i want to load data from dynamic location. What can be the answer ..?

Comment: scripting could solve almost any challenge. example how it could look like: [read file from HDFS](https://javadeveloperzone.com/hadoop/java-read-write-files-hdfs-example/#7_Read_File_From_HDFS). but before moving this way doublecheck that you really have dynamic ip because if you have hdfs cluster defined correctly it should automatically resolve physical file location

Comment: @daggett
path can be dynamic right. Lets say my data is in hourly bucket
2021/11/29/00, 2021/11/29/01 .... ect so this also i need to achieve , If it is not possible using processor, then as you said i need to go with scripting. and also there can be some cases hdfs namenode service will restart , on that time standby namenode will become active one, this also i need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

`FetchHDFS` configuration properties do not have the option to specify  host_ip, Host_name etc. To configure it properly, we have to provide files which contain the Hadoop file system configuration i.e. `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`, and if your Hadoop cluster is using any authentication mechanism then you need to provide those details as well. Please refer to the below working configuration screenshot, copy those files from any of the Hadoop data node and paste on NiFi node (or all the nodes for NiFi cluster setup) and pass Hadoop cluster authentication details if any.

[image: FetchHDFS Properties]

Comment: Lets say if i want to load file from hdfs to Nifi how can we do that..?In that case we need to provide the hdfs path right.? But my concern that how we can dynamically change the path

Comment: If i need to fetch data from hdfs from an hourly bucket , so every hour path will change right .? Thats why i need to give a flow file to this processor, so the flowfile will contain all the attribute like path/NameNode/ etc

Comment: Hi, pleas see the update

Comment: @badhushamuhammed - `HDFS Filename` property  support expression language so the upstream connection can derive/pass value for this property like `${file_to_fetch}` and your `API`  input port should get this attribute from another process group. Otherwise, add a `UpdateAttribute` in between `API` and `FetchHDFS` that will derive `${file_to_fetch}` attribute, and it's value. 

Also, you can use combination like `ListHDFS - FetchHDFS`

Comment: Yes, But `fetchHDFS` is not getting the `flowfile` in `queue` ,the `Flowfile attribute` contains info about paths. pleas look at the image 1. one `queued`. It is not picking by `fetchHDFS`

Comment: `HDFS Filename` property purpose is to set the name of the HDFS file to retrieve, and not to pass Hadoop cluster configuration. To make NiFi aware of your Hadoop cluster, you need to set `Hadoop Configuration Resources`  property value to xml files.